# Unable to find symbols for JSONObject, FileReader, JSONArray in Java

Tags: java, json

I am getting errors that the JSON objects and file reader objects cannot be found. However, I have imported the correct libraries and it still does not work.
The code I have until now is as follows:

```
import org.json.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Test {
    private static HashSet<String> seenAttributes = new HashSet<>();
    public static void parseBusinessData() {
        FileReader fileReader = null;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        String filePath = "C:/Users/jay/documents/c_______/yelp_business.json";
        try {
            fReader = new FileReader(filePath);
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            String line;
            bufferedReader.readLine();
            int index = 0;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(line);
        
                /*
                CREATE TABLE Business_Attributes (
                    Business_Id char(22) NOT NULL,
                    Attribute_Id number(5) NOT NULL,
                
                CREATE TABLE Attributes (
                    Attribute_Id number(5) NOT NULL,
                    Attribute_Name varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
                */

                JSONArray attributeArray = obj.getJSONArray("attributes");

                for(int i = 0; i < attributeArray.length; i++){
                    String attribute = attributeArray.getString(i);
                    System.out.println("Attribute = " + attribute);
                    if(!seenAttributes.contains(attribute)){
                        seenAttributes.add(attribute);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                bufferedReader.close();
                fReader.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        parseBusinessData();
    }
}
```

And I get the following errors:

```
Test.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
            fReader = new FileReader(filePath);
            ^
  symbol:   variable fReader
  location: class Test
Test.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(line);
                ^
  symbol:   class JSONObject
  location: class Test
Test.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(line);
                                     ^
  symbol:   class JSONObject
  location: class Test
Test.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
                JSONArray attributeArray = obj.getJSONArray("attributes");
                ^
  symbol:   class JSONArray
  location: class Test
Test.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
                fReader.close();
                ^
  symbol:   variable fReader
  location: class Test
5 errors
```

It would be great if you could help me resolve these errors! I've spent a lot of time on this and don't seem to know what's the issue here. From what I've read online, I need to download some jar files but I'm not sure which ones.

Comment: What do you think are the correct libraries, and how have you added them?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your `fReader` to `fileReader`
For `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` make sure you have added the required jars from `org.json` in your `classpath`.

Adding jars to `classpath`

Righ click on project -> Build Path -> Configure build path
Select the libraries tab -> Add external jars.

Add all required jars, you can refer image below
[image: buiild path]
[image]

Comment: I've downloaded org.json.jar but I'm unsure how to add it to the classpath. Any tips?

Comment: @jay If you are using eclipse I have added steps to answer

Comment: Hi @SSK, I have done the same thing and have added a json simple jar file to the java build path in Eclipse. However, it still does not work. Do I need to do something more to make this work?

Comment: I run javac file.java in terminal once I have added the jar file to the build path. Is this correct? Do I need additional command line arguments?